# Immutable.js: create a list with one element

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have an Immutable record as follows:

```
export const Pane = new Record({
    'id': null,
    'editors': new List(),
});
```

where `editors` is a list of id strings associated with a pane.

In my Redux reducer code I have:

```
const pane = new Pane({
    id: action.payload.id, 
    editors: new List(action.payload.editorId),
});
```

When the reducer is constructing the `Pane`, however, it creates the `editors` field as an Immutable List, as intended, but rather than having a single string, each character in the string becomes an individual item in the list.

How do I construct an Immutable List with a single object, as intended?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to pass the List constructor an array containing your string(s).
assuming `action.payload.editorId` is a `string`, and not an array of strings;

e.g.

```
const pane = new Pane({
    id: action.payload.id, 
    editors: new List([action.payload.editorId]),
});
```

For more information, check the documentation at https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/List